# What's the name of the song in episode 18 of season 3 of My Hero Academia?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

In episode 18 of season 3 of *My Hero Academia*, the song starts at around 10:40. I feel like I've heard it before, but can't find it anywhere.

What's the song name?

Answer (score 1):

"Cavalry battle" boku no hero academia season 2 :

https://youtu.be/IjBhS8MQSMs